# Samba vulnerability to rpcclient attack

Tags: linux, samba

There is what seems to be a known vulnerability in Samba exploitable via *rpcclient*.  One can use *rpcclient* to access a Samba server, and then by using commands such as *srvinfo*, *enumprivs*, *lookupnames* and *lookupsids*, information valuable to a hacker (OS and platform information, usernames and id's, ...) can be retrieved. With that information in hand passwords might be compromised with a tool such as *hydra*.

A Google search shows me several explanations of this exploit (such as: [Plundering Windows Account Info via Authenticated SMB Sessions](http://pen-testing.sans.org/blog/2013/07/24/plundering-windows-account-info-via-authenticated-smb-sessions) and [Enumerating user accounts on Linux and OS X with rpcclient](http://carnal0wnage.attackresearch.com/2007/07/enumerating-user-accounts-on-linux-and.html)), but I can find no discussion anywhere regarding how to protect against it.

I've tried specifying

```
idmap config * : backend = tdb
```

in *smb.conf*, and nulling out the tdb, but that doesn't prevent a user from discerning OS, root user and more.

Is there a known way to harden against this exploit?  My Samba servers are Ubuntu (various version), and we use Samba 3.6.3.

Comment: try yo search a patch for the bug, because as you told, it's a known issue.

Comment: I've tried searching extensively and found nothing so far.  If you have a pointer that would be appreciated.  It isn't really a bug: both Samba and *rpcclient* are functioning as intended, rather it's a vulnerability.

Answer (score 2):

The normal function of the RPC just represent a risk when your servers allow to establish anonymous sessions (using username ''" and password ''") In this scenario anyone can retrieve the valuable information that you mentioned before using rpclient's commands. So, avoid that your servers permit null sessions and that's it!